# hmailserver SMTP DNS setup

Tags: dns, outlook, smtp, hmail-server

If I have two domains (ex: domain1.com & domain2.com) setup in hmailserver.

What dns records or hmailserver changes do I create to allow these domains to work as the incoming and outgoing mail server in MS Outlook?

I created DNS for domain1.com with MX record and it works but can't get domain2.com to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a DNS record (specifically MX) for domain2.com to get it to work as well. If your hMailServer is already configured to deal with emails from that domain it should just start working away!